# Why my form make postback ,althouth there 's a required field validtion wasn't matched?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, postback, validation

Q:

I have a `RequiredFieldValidator` on my page ,when i click the button which is (`postback triggered`) it makes the `postback`, although the field which is required wasn't entered !
What's the reason to this behavior?

## My .aspx:

```
                       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Search" />
                            </Triggers>
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Search" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" 
                                    OnClick="btn_Search_Click" OnClientClick="return postbackButtonClick();" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

```
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_department" runat="server" Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_department_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddl_department"
                            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="-1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_study" runat="server" Width="200px">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddl_study"
                                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="-1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_department" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

```
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var updateProgress = null;
                            function postbackButtonClick() {
                                updateProgress = $find("<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>");
                                window.setTimeout("updateProgress.set_visible(true)", updateProgress.get_displayAfter());
                                return true;
                            }
                        </script>
```

Comment: Did you set validator's `ValidationGroup` property value?

Comment: no there's no validation group .

Comment: Show code for initializing ddl_department. Does it have ListItem with value -1 selected by default?

Comment: Try setting return "false" instead of "true".

Comment: @Yuriy Rozhovetskiy :Could u give me the last answer again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove return clause from LinkButton's `OnClientClick` property value: `OnClientClick="postbackButtonClick()"` and rewrite `postbackButtonClick` as below:

```
function postbackButtonClick() {
     Page_ClientValidate();

     if (Page_IsValid) {
          updateProgress = $find("<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>");
          window.setTimeout("updateProgress.set_visible(true)", updateProgress.get_displayAfter());
          return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: `ddl_department.Items.Clear();`
                `ddl_department.DataSource = CommonUitilities.DepartmentList(int.Parse(Session["emp"].ToString()));`
                `ddl_department.DataTextField = "dep_name";`
                `ddl_department.DataValueField = "dep_code";`
               ` ddl_department.DataBind();`
               `ddl_department.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select department", "-1"));`
              ` ddl_department.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: Is this existing code or you have had add code for default item just now?

Comment: no this is the existing code , and every thing goes okay before i add the `imagebutton` to the updatepanel with postbacktrigger.

Comment: `<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Search" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" OnClick="btn_Search_Click" />`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
                            function postbackButtonClick() {
                                Page_ClientValidate();

                                if (Page_IsValid) {
                                    updateProgress = $find("<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>");
                                    window.setTimeout("updateProgress.set_visible(true)", updateProgress.get_displayAfter());
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }

                        </script>`

Comment: Don't remove `OnClientClick` completely, just remove return clause from it. Check updated answer.

Comment: `<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Search" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" OnClick="btn_Search_Click"
                                    OnClientClick="postbackButtonClick()" />`

Comment: hmmm, the same problem , postback and doesn't validate.

Comment: Thanks a lot .This fixes my problem but when i validate my file ,i face the same problem.

`<script type="text/javascript">
                            function ValidateRadUpload1(source, arguments) {
                                arguments.IsValid = GetRadUpload('<%= fu.ClientID %>').ValidateExtensions();
                            }
                        </script>`

Comment: `<asp:CustomValidator ID="validateUploader" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select a valid XML file"
                            Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="validateUploader_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateRadUpload1"></asp:CustomValidator>`